# Angular: 'Routes' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here

Tags: angular6

Fresh project using Angular CLI + Angular Material today.

Went to import RouterModule and Routes from @angular/router in the 'app.module.ts' file, added RouterModule and Routes to imports and got this error:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(18,5): error TS2693: 'Routes' only refers to a
type, but is being used as a value here.
```

Not sure how to fix this. Here is the code.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { MatToolbarModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatIconModule, 
         MatListModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  NavigationComponent
],
imports: [
  RouterModule,
  Routes,
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  LayoutModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatListModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More or less as the error describes, `Routes` is a `Type` as opposed to an instantiated or injectable object - so you cant import it into a module. What you *can* do is use it to declare your app routes and then use those when importing the `RouterModule` in order to define the available routes.

Your mistake is here:

[image]

You *cannot import `Routes` - because it is a **TYPE**.* You may only import other Modules.

The docs have a good description of how module imports work, if you're interested: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#angular-modularity

Here is a simple example.

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OneComponent } from './one/one.component';
import { TwoComponent } from './two/two.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
  { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    OneComponent,
    TwoComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I read through the link you sent, but I am also still confused because the guide [https://angular.io/guide/router](https://angular.io/guide/router) shows them putting it into the app.module.ts file as an import and configuring it there.

Comment: I think I understand your confusion now - you are being confused by two different types of imports (typescript file imports vs angular module imports). It is imported into the `app.module.ts` typescript FILE, but not the `AppModule` angular MODULE.

Comment: Ah! so the Routes on the line being imported from @angular/router, is not being imported in the imports array because it is not a module, as you said.

It is instead being used to define the routes type (_routes: Routes_) below the lines of imports. Makes much more sense now. I appreciate the clarified answer, sir. Clearly there is more learning to be done.

Answer (score 0):

After some more reading and courses, I created a new 'app-routing.module.ts' file in the /app folder, and put in the following code, removed the imports for RouterModule and Routes in the 'app.module.ts' file, and the error disappeared:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    // { path: '', component: '' },
    // { path: '', component: '' }
];

@NgModule({

})

export class AppRoutingModule {  }
```

The course I learned this from, however did say that I could have done it the way I did in the OP, but obviously that did not work (unless I was missing something?).

I guess this is the 'recommended' way of doing it, but now it really seems more like the *required* way to do it.

Comment: Its always been the required way to do it, have a look here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#add-routes

Comment: It appears the tutorial differs from the docs there [https://angular.io/guide/router](https://angular.io/guide/router)

Comment: No, it doesnt - have a look at the complete example code: https://stackblitz.com/angular/odlykrbxqox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: I see. Did you also look at the router guide? They are literally doing all of that in the app.module.ts, not only importing RouterModule and Routes, but also defining the routes there. I am not saying the tutorial is wrong, I modeled my solution after the tutorial. I am just saying the guide at the link I posted on the official documentation clearly shows them doing it the other (outdated?) way, which did not work for me. I feel the tutorial *and* the docs should mention this.

Comment: Declaring the routes in the same file is fine (not outdated) - having a separate module is cleaner but absolutely not required. The mistake you were making was that you were trying to import *the _type_ instead of the declared routes*. I'll update my answer to show exactly what I mean.